# Error in writing yml for somewhat similar keys

Tags: spring, yaml

I have two keys - app.user = 'user1' and app.user.age= '21' . I need to write these in yml file. I am getting errors when I am writing these like-

```
1) app:
    user: 'user1'
    age: '21'
```

error: mapping values are not allowed here

```
2) app: 
    user: 'user1'
   app:
    user:
      age:'21'
error: **duplication error**
```

Comment: can you format your code.

Comment: formatting the code is not helping

Comment: I meant format the code here so that others can read it properly

Comment: @AnandKumar If you want people to help you, they need to see exactly the input that you are using. I edited your code, but I can only guess if the `1)` and `2)` in front is really part of your yaml file or not. Would you help somebody if they throw some unformatted code at you, unclear how the files are looking like exactly?

Comment: Also, please tell us which YAML processor you are using. I assume SnakeYAML?

Comment: @tinita, thanks for the editing...yes I am using snake yaml..

Answer (score 1):

Your data model contradicts itself when interpreted as YAML data, if we assume that the notation `x.y` has the semantics *the value of `y` in a mapping referred to by `x`*. Note that this notation is not defined within YAML. Based on this assumption, here's the contradiction:

```
app.user = 'user1'        (1)
app.user.age= '21'        (2)
```

Claim `(1)` means:

> The value of *app* is a *mapping*. This mapping contains a key *user* whose value is a scalar with the content `user1`.

Claim `(2)` means:

> The value of *app* is a *mapping*. This mapping contains a key *user* whose value is **also a mapping**. In that mapping, there is a key *age* with value `21`.

The contradiction is obvious: `app.user` cannot be a scalar value as implied by claim `(1)` and a mapping as implied by claim `(2)`at the same time. So the solution obviously is to remove the contradiction from your data model. One possible way to do this is:

```
app:
  user:
    id: 'user1'
    age: '21'
```

As for the duplication error: YAML forbids a mapping to contain equal keys. In your code, you have two keys `app` in the root mapping, which causes the error.

**Note:**

I am aware that there *are* data serialisations that allow a key having a simple *and* a complex value at the same time. I can only guess you got the idea for your model from there. It is not inherently wrong, just not supported by YAML. Boost's INFO file format is one of those formats.

**Edit:**

If you disagree with my assumption above about the semantics of `x.y`, you probably come from Java land where `java.lang` and `java.util` have absolutely nothing to do with each other except for their names having the same prefix. Most importantly, they are *not* child packages of the package `java` (if that surprises you, read the section *Apparent Hierarchies of Packages* in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)).

Following this semantics, there is no hierarchy in your data, and thus, no hierarchy in your YAML. instead of writing nested mappings, you would write:

```
app.user: 'user1'
app.user.age: '21'
```

Note that the `.` is not a special YAML character, but just a part of the value's key.